# See what objects ContentDocument is linked to and get the count per objects

Tags: soql, dynamic-soql, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

To keep it simple, I want to know to which Objects are linked my Attachments, so I executed the following SOQL query :

```
select count(id), Parent.type counter from Attachment
 
group by Parent.type
```

I get the result I want with the count for each object.

My problem now is I want to do the Same for ContentDocument/ContentVersion  I know to do it for a specific object I would do :

```
SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink WHERE LinkedEntityId IN (SELECT Id FROM Account)
```

And I will get the count for Account. Thing is I want to know for all objects because my goal is to know how many Document are linkes to each object and have an overview, so I cannot list myself each objects in salesforce to find it. Is there a way to do that in one go ?
This would not work :
SELECT Id, LinkedEntityId, ContentDocumentId FROM ContentDocumentLink

Because I get Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.

Maybe with APEX ?

---

Edit :
The QueryAll  document followed with this query did the trick :

```
SELECT COUNT(Id), LinkedEntity.type
FROM ContentDocumentLink
GROUP BY LinkedEntity.type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to query this directly from Salesforce. However, you can enable the [Query All Files](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000381258&type=1) permission, query all the metadata to your local device, then use Excel, MySQL, etc to analyze the data.

Comment: Thank you, I think this will do with a bit of work.